# How to check Hadoop Datanode and Namenode with shell script?

Tags: shell, hadoop

How to check Hadoop Datanode and Namenode with shell script ?
i could not use `hdfs dfs -report` without permission.

Comment: In other words,list all datanode.

Comment: Well, what have you tried to "get permission"? You'll need an authenticated user with any method you try